# How to Create Searchable Field or Searchable Dropdown in Flutter with Api?

Tags: flutter, api

I have to Create Searchable Field or Searchable Dropdown which search the data from api based on criteria.

Here is API to search data.

```
http://143.110.248.5:20080/api/v1/staff/search?s=criteria
```

This is my Function for get the data.

```
static const String API_GET_STAFF = "staff/search?";

Future<Staff?> getStaffDetails(String staff) async {
    User userData = DataManager.instance.getUser();
    Map<String, String> headers = {"Authorization": userData.authToken!};
    Map<String, String> params = {
      "s=": staff,
    };
    var req = RestRequest(reqUrl: API_GET_STAFF)
      ..reqMethod = RequestMethod.METHOD_GET
      ..header = headers
      ..params = params;

    Response res = await req.dioSend();

    return Staff.fromHashMap(res.data!["dataList"]);
  }
```

above function  returns

```
Response ({"responseCode":406,"responseMessage":"Please provide search criteria!","data":null,"dataList":null,"excelDataList":null,"totalRecords":0,"pageRecords":0,"currentPageNumber":0,"totalPages":0})
```

and if i pass data in API_GET_STAFF api like below.

```
static const String API_GET_STAFF = "staff/search?s=dhaval";
```

its return proper response.

So here is my two problem.

First is the Response.
and Second is How to Create Searchable Field or Searchable Dropdown for this api?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this needs to be without the `=`

```
Map<String, String> params = {
  "s=": staff,
};
```

so like

```
Map<String, String> params = {
  "s": staff,
};
```

And your other question I think is too broad.

Comment: I tried this but its returns "responseMessage":"Please provide search criteria!",